# file.copy is not working in same directory

Tags: r

I am trying to make a copy of file ABC in same directory and rename

```
dirPath ="P:\\test\\"

fileABC =paste("file",  format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"), format(Sys.Date(), "%m"), sep="")

previousDate =as.Date(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y-%m-01')) - 1
previousDate2 =as.Date(format(previousDate, '%Y-%m-01')) - 1

fileXYZ =paste("file",  format(previousDate2, "%Y"), format(previousDate2, "%m"),".csv", sep="")

setwd(dirPath)
file.copy(file.path(dirPath, fileABC), dirPath, overwrite = FALSE)
file.rename(list.files(pattern=" - Copy.csv"), paste0(fileXYZ,".csv"))
```

Comment: What is the error? What are actual representative values you've tried for your variables? What does it mean to rename multiple files to a single file name?

Comment: there is no error but the expected file (fileABC - copy.csv) is not being created. When i tried another path instead of same path, it is working.

Comment: my idea is to run this script for automating a quirky manual process. where i access this directory and copy paste previous month file (file201712) and rename it to current month (file201801).

Comment: `fileABC`, `dirPath`, `dirPath2`, `fileXYZ`, ... LoopBloke, please make this question reproducible. To do so, I suggest you create (verbosely, so that people like me can test locally) some temporary files in a temporary directory, then create actual variables that point to these files correctly, and then show us what code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
todir<-tempdir()
file.copy(file.path(dirPath, fileABC), tempdir(), overwrite = FALSE)
file.rename(file.path(todir, fileABC),paste0(file.path(todir, fileABC),"_copy"))
file.copy(paste0(file.path(todir, fileABC),"_copy"), dirPath, overwrite = FALSE)
file.rename(paste0(file.path(dirPath, fileABC),"_copy"), file.path(dirPath, fileXYZ))
```